# Please help a regular expression problem for a string

Tags: regex, string, find, character

String aa = "aa\nbb\r\ncc";

I want to have a regular expression pattern to find the "\n" , but skip the "\r\n" .   Thanks so much if anyone can help it ?

Answer (score 0):

`pattern = (?<!\\r)\\n`

I don't know which language you're using, but in Python this should work:

```
import re
pattern = r'(?<!\\r)\\n'
search_string = r'aa\nbb\r\ncc'
match = re.search(pattern, search_string)
print(match.group(0))
```

It uses a "negative lookbehind".
You can test the pattern on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hw0ZpD/1)
You can also try running the code [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)